# How to make a drawn shape stay on the screen? LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx

Currently I have a float value set to draw a rectangle to the screen once the delta time reaches 4, and once the value reaches four the rectangle will stay on the screen for a split second and then disappear. How do I make it so that it will stay on the screen, because I'd like to have a new rectangle appear  every 4 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to make rectangles after every four seconds and you want them to stay on the screen. I guess what you might be doing is repositioning the same rectangle everytime and that is why you see the rectangle disappear.

Anyways, here is how you do this:

## Draw a function that will keep creating rectangles for you

```
private void spawnRectangle() {
    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
    myRectangle .x = MathUtils.random(0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-400);
    myRectangle .y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    myRectangle .setSize(400,40);
    myList.add(myRectangle); //you need this list to store all the rectangles
}
```

So in the above code, i am making rectangles randomly in the x-axis and topmost at the y-axis.

## Now call this function every 4 sec

```
timeTracker+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
if(timeTracker>=4){
  timeTracker=0;
}
```

## Now draw the sprites to the position of these rectangles

```
    for(Rectangle myRectangle: myList) {
        batch.draw(mySprite, myRectangle.x, myRectangle.y,myRectangle.width,myRectangle.height);
    }
```

Comment: I wasn't sure what (bar) was so I have myList.add(myRectangle) instead. This is giving me an error in the for loop and says that I cannot convert from an object to a rectangle

Comment: `myList.add(myRectangle);` Yeah it was supposed to be myRectangle and not the bar, sorry for that , i edited the code and glad to see your code worked.